# Voltage Earth Leakage Module wiring

Tags: power-electronics, rcd

This is an old 4x125 A, 0.03-3 A Adjustable Earth Leakage Module (EL), 26013 DPX 125 Legrand, fitted aside a 3x125 A Moulded Case Circuit Breaker (MCCB), 25041 DPX 125 Legrand.

It was installed as a replacement for a Residual Current Device (RCD, RCCB), but instead of having 3 P+N in - 3P+N out, has only 3P+N in (?).

Besides, it was discontinued; I have not found it in any catalog anywhere.

I think this device must be wired in parallel and below its respective MCCB, so it can trigger it mechanically interlocked when EL detects a fault.

Instead of measuring current (as a normal RCD or an ampere meter)(?) it looks wired for measuring voltage (as a voltage meter)(?), hence should be less precise (?). Worse, it seems, it was wired elsewhere (!?).

How should this EL device be connected? Is it indeed equivalent to an RCD?

[image]

Comment: I found an old Legrand catalog that lists DPX 125 ELMs "0260 13 Side by side" and "0260 14 Underneath", so side-by-side seems entirely correct for this unit. I can't answer the rest of how it works, but probably there are some hidden connections.

Comment: I also have the CB catalog and some old catalogs mentioning that mounting product options.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy to find with one google search at https://ecataleg.nl/documize/2012/11/20121113_69247_2.pdf

[image]

Comment: This is the CB catalog. It includes the EL, but do not includes the EL wiring.